# Add entity data model (edmx file) to .net core API

Tags: api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have .Net Core 5.0 API project contains another .Net Core Class Library.

Also I have exiting SQl Server Database.

How can create edmx using .net core project with my exiting databse?

C# and VS2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core do not support `edmx`. It uses attributes and Fluent API for defining schema and mapping.

Check this link how to work with existing database with EF Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an EDMX file in .NET core but you can use an existing edmx file in .NET core project. I documented the procedure [here](https://dev.to/ashirafumiiro/using-edmx-file-and-t4-in-net-core-to-generate-code-entities-dto-api-services-etc-ic5) and a code sample on [github](https://github.com/ashirafumiiro/T4CodeGeneration).
You can even generate more than entities, including an entire API